# Firebase, update a specific field

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to update a specific field of current information on firebase.

The closest I've gotten is 
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.firebase.client.Firebase&method=updateChildren

But I can't seem to figure it out.

```
package com.example.updatefirebase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Connects to my database.
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
        userMap.put("name", "lol");
        userMap.put("image", "321321");
        userMap.put("image_thumbnail", "default");


        //Trying to write to root file.
       // databaseReference.setValue(userMap);

        Map<String, Object> mapaCompleto = new HashMap<>();
        mapaCompleto.put(lol, userMap);


        //Update firebase.
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").updateChildren(mapaCompleto);

    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do, is the outcomment my databaseReference.setValue(userMap);

And then update a specific place in my database. Like the name, from lol to joey, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateChildren()`:

```
HashMap<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
userMap.put("name", "joey");
userMap.put("image", "321321");
userMap.put("image_thumbnail", "default");

databaseReference.updateChildren(userMap);
```

`updateChildren()` will update a specific field without overwriting other child nodes.

You can find more info in the following link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: Found out, it was easier to use:

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child("name").setValue("joey");

Answer (score -1):

Found out it was easier just to write:

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child("name").setValue("joey");

Because I am not going to have the information put in place, given users will eventually fill out my database with their own stuff.

I'd probably have to set it up with a getter setter method otherwise.

But for single information changes, this is by far the easiest, as I do know the path.